# android EditText lagging when typing text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, lag

Im developing some sort of chat application, all goes wellm but im stuck with one problem.
EditText lags, my android keyboard gets freezed on second or some whenever I type some letter in edittext. O din't really know what code to provide, because it's just a simple EditText box. Here's how i make it:

```
linforbutton.add(new LinearLayout(this));  //linear layout on the bottom os creen for edittext and button
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
      new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    linforbutton.get(x).setLayoutParams(params);
    linforbutton.get(x).setBackgroundColor(0xff426193);
    linforbutton.get(x).setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    int padding_in_dp1 = 3;  
    final float scale1 = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding_in_px1 = (int) (padding_in_dp1 * scale1 + 0.5f);
    linforbutton.get(x).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    relmsg.get(x).addView(linforbutton.get(x));
    msginput.add(new EditText(this));
    msginput.get(x).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    msginput.get(x).setMaxLines(3);
    msginput.get(x).setMinLines(1);
    msginput.get(x).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
    msginput.get(x).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    msginput.get(x).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
    msginput.get(x).setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND);
    msginput.get(x).setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
    linforbutton.get(x).addView(msginput.get(x));
    btninput.add(new Button(this));
    btninput.get(x).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btninput.get(x).setText("Отпр.");
    int padding_in_dp2 = 20;  
    final float scale2 = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding_in_px2 = (int) (padding_in_dp2 * scale2 + 0.5f);
    btninput.get(x).setPadding(padding_in_px2, 0, padding_in_px2, 0);
    linforbutton.get(x).addView(btninput.get(x));
```

Im making some views so i have a for loop, dont look at the arrays. I tried removing arrays and making only one view one edittext one button and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads / or async tasks?

Comment: I have 6 threads total in my app

Comment: Well that is probably your problem then. See if you can add some pauses to some of your threads to improve performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that your threads may conflict with each other. Look around your event listeners, maybe one of them holds the process. I had this problem a while ago with my GPS listeners (onLocationChanged).

I posted the data to the server from this listener and it just killed the application. After moving that block of code to a new thread it solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah seems that's the problem. I needed to access my GUI Thread from another thread to draw something, but eventually i pushed all my listener to main thread.